# Why doesn't Flyway skip baseline migration if all the previous migrations were executed?

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

I have over 250 migrations on my project, all executed on production. All the migrations were like this `V1_249__migration_name`, `V1_250__migration_name`... So I created new migration called `V2_0__baseline` which contains the structure of the whole database along with some inserts. Example:

```java
@Component
public class V2_0__baseline extends BaseJavaMigration {
    private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    public V2_0__baseline(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void migrate(Context context) throws Exception {
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:baseline/baseline.sql");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(resource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        String sql = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();

        context.getConnection().createStatement().execute(sql);
    }
}
```

This is my flyway configuration:

```yaml
  flyway:
    out-of-order: true
    enabled: true
    baseline-version: 2.0
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    baseline-description: My baseline
```

Idea was to create a way to support both running migrations on empty database and running them on production. There's some issues with some of the old migrations and we can't simply run migrations on an empty database, it breaks on so many places. So that's why i wanted to create baseline which contains all the structure and it would be easy to run it on an empty database. And this works completely fine when I run on an empty database. But when I run it on a database that already has executed migrations, instead of skipping baseline migration, it executes it. I don't understand what is happening exactly, is this intended behavior? If not, what am I doing wrong? If yes, how can I solve the problem I'm having?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `V2_0__baseline` name it `B1__baseline`. The prefix Bn tells Flyway to treat it as a baseline script which includes all migrations up to and including n. It will be executed only on an empty database.

Please note: The baselines are not included in the free edition. Only in the Flyway Teams.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible, I'm using flyway-core 9.5.1 dependency, and prefix B is not used anymore, only V and R.

Comment: OK. I see. The baselines are not included in the free edition. Only in the Flyway Teams.

Comment: Baselines are included in the free edition, they just work a little bit differently. As you can see in my flyway configuration, I am able to set baseline versions, and it actually works in an empty database. But when I try to set the baseline in a database that contains executed migrations, baseline migration also gets executed, but my understanding is that it should be skipped.